# SPSS syntax: how can I generate a var_list of all variables from the active dataset?

Tags: spss

Frequently, PSPP/SPSS syntax documentation ([example](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/manual/html_node/DESCRIPTIVES.html)) suggests I must to pass a list of variables with `/VARIABLES=var_list` and this is not an optional subcommand.

But I have a lot of datasets to process. I would like to programmatically get a list of all variables in the active dataset, pass that to a procedure, and then generate a file from the procedure output.

I've tried `/VARIABLES=*` but that didn't work.

`` error: DESCRIPTIVES: Syntax error at `*': expecting variable name. ``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display variables.`  or `display dictionary.` to generate a table of all variables and their attributes which could then be captured using OMS.  However if you want to pass all variables to a function that expects a list you can use `all`, i.e. `descriptives /variables= all.`.

Answer (score 2):

`/VARIABLES` is often optional in procedures, but ALL stands for all the variables.  If you need to refine by a particular measurement level, type or other metadata, try the `SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES` extension command. This command applies various filters based on the metadata and creates a macro with the variables that pass.  You can then use that in any context.