# SPSS group by rows and concatenate string into one variable

Tags: aggregate, string-concatenation, spss

I'm trying to [export SPSS metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405052/export-spss-metadata-variable-labels-value-labels-data-types-etc-to-custom-te/67405963#67405963) to a custom format using SPSS syntax. The dataset with value labels contains one or more labels for the variables.

However, now I want to concatenate the value labels into one string per variable. For example for the variable `SEX` combine or group the rows `F`/`Female` and `M`/`Male` into one variable `F=Female;M=Male;`. I already concatenated the code and labels into a new variable using `Compute CodeValueLabel = concat(Code,'=',ValueLabel).`
so the starting point for the source dataset is like this:

```
+--------------+------+----------------+------------------+
| VarName      | Code | ValueLabel     | CodeValueLabel   |
+--------------+------+----------------+------------------+
| SEX          | F    | Female         | F=Female         |
| SEX          | M    | Male           | M=Male           |
| ICFORM       | 1    | Yes            | 1=Yes            |
| LIMIT_DETECT | 0    | Too low        | 0=Too low        |
| LIMIT_DETECT | 1    | Normal         | 1=Normal         |
| LIMIT_DETECT | 2    | Too high       | 2=Too high       |
| LIMIT_DETECT | 9    | Not applicable | 9=Not applicable |
+--------------+------+----------------+------------------+
```

The goal is to get a dataset something like this:

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| VarName      | group_and_concatenate                           |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| SEX          | F=Female;M=Male;                                |
| ICFORM       | 1=Yes;                                          |
| LIMIT_DETECT | 0=Too low;1=Normal;2=Too high;9=Not applicable; |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried using [CASESTOVARS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/24.0.0?topic=casestovars-examples-command) but that creates separate variables, so several variables not just one single string variable. I'm starting to suspect that I'm running up against the limits of what SPSS can do. Although maybe it's possible using some `AGGREGATE` or `OMS` trickery, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hey, "running up against the limits of SPSS"?? a little more credit ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I recreate your example here to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/varName CodeValueLabel (2a30).
begin data
"SEX"  "F=Female"
"SEX"  "M=Male"
"ICFORM"  "1=Yes"
"LIMIT_DETECT"  "0=Too low"
"LIMIT_DETECT"  "1=Normal"
"LIMIT_DETECT"  "2=Too high"
"LIMIT_DETECT"  "9=Not applicable"
end data.
```

Now to work:

```
* sorting to make sure all labels are bunched together.
sort cases by varName CodeValueLabel.
string combineall (a300).
* adding ";" .
compute combineall=concat(rtrim(CodeValueLabel), ";").
* if this is the same varname as last row, attach the two together.
if $casenum>1 and varName=lag(varName)  
     combineall=concat(rtrim(lag(combineall)), " ", rtrim(combineall)).
exe.
*now to select only relevant lines - first I identify them.
match files /file=* /last=selectthis /by varName.
*now we can delete the rest.
select if selectthis=1.
exe.
```

NOTE: make `combineall` wide enough to contain all the values of your most populated variable.

Comment: Okay so it's a combination of using `SORT` and `LAG` and `$casenum` I don't have that much experience with SPSS so this helped a lot. :) This was the last puzzle piece to completing the script to export SPSS metadata to REDCap, thanks so much

Comment: Happy to help! Note that there are other possible solutions - including restructuring with `casestovars` and then attaching together the new variables created - but I thought my solution above was easier to automate in this context.