# Syntax to generate a Syntax in SPSS

Tags: syntax, spss

I’m trying to construct a Syntax to generate a Syntax in SPSS, but I’m having some issues…
I have an excel file with metadata and I would like to use it in order to make a syntax to extract information from it (like this, if I have a huge database, I just need to keep the excel updated – add/delete variables, etc. - and then run a syntax to extract the needed information for a new syntax).
I also noticed the produced syntax has always around 15Mb, which is a lot (applied to more than 500 lines)!
I don’t use Python due to run syntax in different computers and/or configurations.
Any ideas? Can anyone please help me?
Thank you in advance.

Example:
(test.xlsx – sheet 1)
Var Code Label List Var_label (concatenate Var+Label)
V1 3 Sex 1 V1 “Sex”
V2 1 Work 2 V2 “Work”
V3 3 Country 3 V3 “Country”
V4 1 Married 2 V4 “Married”
V5 1 Kids 2 V5 “Kids”
V6 2 Satisf1 4 V6 “Satisf1”
V7 2 Satisf2 4 V7 “Satisf2”

(information from other file)
List = 1
1 “Male”
2 “Female”
List = 2
1 “Yes”
2 “No”
List = 3
1 “Europe”
2 “America”
3 “Asia”
4 “Africa”
5 “Oceania”
List = 4
1 “Very unsatisfied”
10 “Very satisfied”

I want to make a Syntax that generates a new syntax to apply “VARIABLE LABELS” and “VALUE LABELS”. So, I thought about something like this:

```
GET DATA
/TYPE=XLSX
/FILE="test.xlsx"
/SHEET=name 'sheet 1'
/CELLRANGE=FULL
/READNAMES=ON
/DATATYPEMIN PERCENTAGE=95.0.
EXECUTE.

STRING vlb (A15) labels (A150) value (A12) lab (A1500) point (A2) separate (A50) space (A2) list1 (A100) list2 (A100).

SELECT IF (Code=1).
COMPUTE vlb = "VARIABLE LABELS".
COMPUTE labels = CONCAT (RTRIM(Var_label)," ").
COMPUTE point = ".".
COMPUTE value = "VALUE LABELS".
COMPUTE lab = CONCAT (RTRIM(Var)," ").
COMPUTE list1 = '1 " Yes "'.
COMPUTE list2 = '2 "No".'.
COMPUTE space = " ".
COMPUTE separate="************************************************.".

WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" / vlb.
WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" /labels.
WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" /point.
WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" /value.
WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" /lab.
WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" /list1.
WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" /list2.
WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" /space.
WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" /separate.
WRITE OUTFILE = "list_01.sps" /space.
```

If there is only one variable with same list (ex: V1), it works ok. However, if there is more than one variable having the same list, it reproduces the codes as much times as number of variables (Ex: V2, V4 and V5).

What I have (Ex: V2, V4 and V5), after running code above:

VARIABLE LABELS
V2 "Work"
.
VALUE LABELS
V2
1 " Yes "
2 " No "
************************************************.
VARIABLE LABELS
V4 "Married"
.
VALUE LABELS
V4
1 " Yes "
2 " No "
************************************************.
VARIABLE LABELS
V5 "Kids"
.
VALUE LABELS
V5
1 " Yes "
2 " No "
************************************************.

What I would like to have:

VARIABLE LABELS
V2 "Work"
V4 "Married"
V5 "Kids"
.
VALUE LABELS
V2 V4 V5
1 " Yes "
2 " No "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are probably ways to automate the whole process better, including the use of your second data source. But for the scope of this question I will suggest a way to get what you asked for specifically.

The key is to build the command with special conditions for first and last lines:

```
string cmd1 cmd2 (a200).
sort cases by code.
match files /file=* /first=first /last=last /by code. /* marking first and last lines.
do if first.
    compute cmd1="VARIABLE LABELS".
    compute cmd2="VALUE LABELS".
end if.
if not first cmd1=concat(rtrim(cmd1), " /"). /* "/" only appears from the second varname.
compute cmd1=concat(rtrim(cmd1), " ", Var_label).
compute cmd2=concat(rtrim(cmd2), " ", Var).
do if last.
    compute cmd1=concat(rtrim(cmd1), " .").
    compute cmd2=concat(rtrim(cmd2), " ", '  1 " Yes "  2 "No". ').
end if.
exe.
```

The commands are now ready, but we don't want to get them mixed up so we'll stack them one under the other, and only then write them out:

```
add files /file=* /rename cmd1=cmd /file=* /rename cmd2=cmd.
exe.
WRITE OUTFILE = "var definitions.sps" / cmd .
exe.
```

**EDIT:**
Note that the code above assumes you've already run a `select cases if code = ...`  and that there is a single `code` in all the remaining lines.
Note also I added an `exe.` command at the end - without running that the new syntax will appear empty.

Comment: One small thing... Isn't it possible to include in your Syntax code a reference to (directly) extract lists from another excel file (or different sheet in same file test.xlsx)? If I have a list with more than 100 entries (ex: country) it will create a huge line for VALUE LABELS. Thanks in advance for helping in this last issue.

Comment: It can be done but you should start this as a new question. On the other hand - first take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416068/spss-group-by-rows-and-concatenate-string-into-one-variable/67417223#67417223), you might have enough there to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot once again! I follow your proposed post and it just works! :) I'm very glad! To be perfect I just needed to have the values labels by line (if possible) because I have more than 450 labels and that will make everything in one line to be huge (maybe need to create a string variable with length A10000.)

Comment: Well this should be a new question with an example, will help find solution